# When creating a new python project on pycharm community edition, I am getting a prompt to select an enviorment, and need some assistance

Tags: python

When creating a new python project on pycharm community edition, I am getting a prompt to select an environment, and wonder what the different options change

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at their documentation here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html

Basically, you need to create an isolated environment to install dependencies for Python in Pycharm. It is a good practice and a recommended approach for most cases.

I usually select `virtualenv` or `conda` option. You just have to choose 1 for now and you can study more about those later.

If you do not have Python installed on your local system, you can consider installing miniconda from here: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Comment: No problem. Let me know how it goes!